# Meaning of The Eigenvalues and Eigenvectors of a Quantum Operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, linear-algebra, eigenvalue

This is more a check to ensure I know the physical meaning of eigenvectors and eigenvalues in quantum mechanics, and to ask the general community if this is wrong:

On some observable, represented by the operator $\hat{Q}$ the eigenfunction of this operator is as follows:
$$\hat{Q} f = qf$$

Where $q$ is the eigenvalue of the operator. In this case, $q$ represents values that one could get while attempting to measure $\hat{Q}$, and the eigenvector produced by $q$ is the state that the system is in at the time of the measurement that produces $q$. Is this right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ..the eigenvector produced by  is the state that the system is in at the time of the measurement that produces .

That's not correct.  Eigenvectors aren't "produced" by an eigenvalue: eigenvectors are "produced" by the operator $\hat Q$, inasmuch as "produced" is understood to mean "vectors (or functions) on which the operator acts by multiplying the original vectors by numbers".  Synonyms for "eigenvectors" are *proper vectors* (in French *vecteurs propres*) or sometimes *characteristic vectors*.  Characteristic vectors is good because it implies that the eigenvectors are enough to characterize the operator.

If the system is prepared in an eigenstate or eigenfunction $f$ of $\hat Q$, then measuring the observable $Q$ will *always* yield the outcome $q$, and $q$ is the only outcome from a measurement of $\hat Q$ with the system prepared in the state $f$.

If you make a measurement of $Q$ and obtain the result $q$, then yes the system will "collapse" to an eigenstate of $Q$, and evolve from that collapsed state thereafter.  If there is more than one eigenstate with this eigenvalue, things are a little more complicated as you can get linear combinations of those eigenstates with eigenvalue $q$.